# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin[\cos x]}{1+[\cos x]}$ where $[.]$ Denotes GIF is equal to?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin[\cos x]}{1+[\cos x]}$$ where $[.]$ Denotes GIF is equal to ?

Attempt: 
Tried taking 1 inside in the denominator and converting it to $2\cos^{2}\frac{x}{2}$ but unable to simplify numerator , how do i approach ?

Comment: What is the range of $\cos x$? Relate this to the greatest integer function. What are the possible outcomes for $[\cos x]$?

Comment: $-1,0$ will be possible outcomes so as x tends to zero $[\cos x]$ will be $0$ ?

Comment: As $x\to0$, from either the left or right, only one of your outcomes is possible. Which one? What does this do for your original limit?

Comment: Yupe thats the correct answer Okay thanks